# PHP / HTML: Optionally add further filter options to search a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Currently, I have a dropdown menu to select a specific column of a table in my database with a text field to search through column for matches. Nothing special so far, it just looks something like this:

```
<select name="option" id="option">
   <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="option1" name="option1"><br>
```

Now I would like to add more filter options, where I don't want to just write this code excerpt repeatedly one below the other. What I would like most is to be able to **press something like a plus button and thus select another filter option**.

[image]

I have no idea what to call this function or how to implement this. Anyone here who could help me please?

Comment: You need to create a simple function for create options with javascript, this function will create the same select (with same name), then in PHP you will foreach and add the option for your query :) Let's go now, return if you will stuck.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thanks for the comment, I don't think that create options is what I'm looking for. I think I have expressed myself wrongly, sorry! I just edited the example picture for a bit more clarification, but I think that I'm looking for something like PHP Geek's example.

Comment: The option is name of row mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to clone your box (textbox and dropdown) - Here you can use the clone component to clone your elements

```
    <style>
    .d-none{
      display:none;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="clone_component_1">
    <select name="option" id="option">
       <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="text" id="option1" name="option1">
    <div class="">
           <a href="javascript:;" onclick="remove_component(this, '1')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-bold remove_component_button_1 remove-button d-none"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="clone_component(this, '1')" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-bold clone_component_button_1 add-button"/><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
    </div>
 </div>
    
    <script>
    //clone component
    window.clone_component = function (t, n) {
        var tr = $(t).closest('.clone_component_' + n);
        var clone = tr.clone();
        clone.find('input,textarea').val('');
        tr.after(clone);
        clone.find('.remove_component_button_' + n).removeClass("d-none");
        if ($('.clone_component_' + n).length > 1) {
            $('.remove_component_button_' + n).removeClass("d-none");
        }
    }
    
    //remove component
    window.remove_component = function (t, n) {
        if ($('.clone_component_' + n).length !== 1) {
            $(t).closest('.clone_component_' + n).remove();
            console.log('.clone_component_' + n);
            console.log($('.clone_component_' + n).length);
            if ($('.clone_component_' + n).length === 1) {
                $('.remove_component_button_' + n).addClass("d-none");
            } else {
                $('.remove_component_button_' + n).eq(($('.clone_component_' + n).length - 1)).removeClass("d-none");
            }
        } else {
            $('.remove_component_button_' + n).addClass("d-none");
        }
        $('.clone_component_button_' + n).eq(($('.clone_component_' + n).length - 1)).removeClass("d-none");
    }
    
    </script>
```

try to use css and elements accordingly but this is and idea how you can clone the elements

Comment: Thank you, I think that cloning components thing is what I'm looking for. However, the plus/minus symbols are not displayed. Is there something (besides the stylesheet of course) I have to add/change?

Answer (score 0):

PHP Geek's didn't work 100% (for me), but it put me on the right track. After a lot of trying and searching, I found a great video that fits perfectly for me. I have taken the values from my opening question so it is more understandable:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            var html = '<div><select name="option[]" class="dropdownmenu" id="childoption"><option value="">- Select option -</option><option value="option1">option 1</option><option value="option2">option 2</option><option value="option3">option 3</option><option value="option4">option 4</option></select><input type="text" name="searchword[]" class="searchfield" id="childsearchword"> <a href="#" id="remove"><button type="button" class="rmvbtn">remove</button></a></div>';
            var maxNumberOfFilters = 5;
            var currNumberOfFilters = 1;

            // add more filters
            $("#add").click(function(e) {
                if (currNumberOfFilters < maxNumberOfFilters) {
                    $("#container-item").append(html);
                    currNumberOfFilters++;
                }
            });

            // remove filter
            $("#container-item").on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                currNumberOfFilters--;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container-item">
        <select name="option[]" class="dropdownmenu" id="option">
            <option value="">- Select option -</option>
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        </select>
        
        <input type="text" name="searchword[]" class="searchfield" id="searchword">
        
        <a href="#" id="add"><button type="button" class="addbtn">add</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Of course, the classes "dropdownmenu", "searchfield", "addbtn" and "rmvbtn" must be added to the stylesheet.

Also, I would like to point out who published this video: 
YouTuber "phpBasics", Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBAPbCDGCuY